# sending random ids - Laravel email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

Good day

I'm using Mailgun to send emails to the users with required info from the order after submitting the form,I managed to send the subject and the email address ,but I'm having trouble sending the random number that gets assigned on the creation of the order.

here is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = $user->orders()->create([

            'randomid' => rand(100000,999999),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
    ]);

    $data = $request->only('subject', 'email', 'randomid');

    Mail::send('emails.note',
        $data
        , function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->subject('New Order: '.$data['subject'])
                ->from('myemail@myserver.com')
                ->to($data['email']);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you get the $data from request object

```
$data = $request->only('subject', 'email', 'randomid');
```

but randomid was generated in created method

```
    $order = $user->orders()->create([

        'randomid' => rand(100000,999999),
        'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
]);
```

So there is not  `randomid` in request.

I think you should get $data  from $order like the folowing:

```
$data = $order->toArray();
```

So You will have:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = $user->orders()->create([

            'randomid' => rand(100000,999999),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
    ]);

    $data = $order->toArray();

    Mail::send('emails.note',
        $data
        , function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->subject('New Order: '.$data['subject'])
                ->from('myemail@myserver.com')
                ->to($data['email']);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `randomid` doesn't come from the request. You generate its value manually using `rand(100000,999999)` !

Please try this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = [
        'randomid' => rand(100000, 999999) , 
        'subject' => $request->input('subject') , 
        'email' => $request->input('email')
    ];
    $order = $user->orders()->create($data);
    Mail::send('emails.note', $data, function ($message) use($data) {
        $message->subject('New Order: ' . $data['subject'])
        ->from('myemail@myserver.com')->to($data['email']);
    });
}
```